# Why I'm getting "undefined local variable or method `rails_env'"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, capistrano, capistrano3

I'm getting `undefined local variable or method 'rails_env'`when doing

> execute "cd #{current_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:stop"

I'm not a big capistrano or rails expert.

On deploy.rb I have

```
namespace :solr do
  desc "start solr"
  task :start do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "cd #{current_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start"
    end
  end

  desc "stop solr"
  task :stop do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "cd #{current_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:stop"
    end
  end

  desc "reindex the whole database"
  task :reindex do
    on roles(:app) do
      invoke 'solr:stop'
      execute "rm -rf #{shared_path}/solr/data/*"
      invoke 'solr:start'
      execute "cd #{current_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} d"
    end
  end

  desc "Symlink in-progress deployment to a shared Solr index"
  task :symlink do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "ln -s #{shared_path}/solr/data/ #{release_path}/solr/data"
      execute "ln -s #{shared_path}/solr/pids/ #{release_path}/solr/pids"
      invoke 'solr:reindex'
    end
  end
end

after "deploy:finishing", "solr:symlink"
```

And on deploy/staging.rb I have

```
 set :rails_env, :staging
```

What's missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `fetch` method. So, instead of `rails_env` use:

```
fetch(:rails_env)
```

[Here](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/how-can-i-access-stage-configuration-variables/) (or [here](http://capistranorb.com/2013/06/01/release-announcement.html#better-magic-variable-support)) is more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `rails_env` with `Rails.env`

Comment: I tested many things... but I believe that was what the original code had and didn't work. i'll give it another try though

Comment: ah, my bad. not a capistrano expert myself. :) looks like maxd might have it